# onmouseover area shows div content at mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, position, mouse, onmouseover, area

Why do this code doesn't work with firefox and ie?
I am using ie 10 and firefox 25, with chrome it works without problems.
Firefox shows the div but not at the right position (mouse coordinates).

The javascript:

```
<script>
    function show(id) {
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
      var topPixel = event.clientY; 
      var leftPixel = event.clientX; 
      document.getElementById(id).style.top = topPixel + "px"; 
      document.getElementById(id).style.left = leftPixel + "px";
    };
    function hide(id) {
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
    };
</script>
```

The css:

```
<style>
.show {display: none;position:absolute;}
</style>
```

The html with php($data is read correctly):

```
<img src="picture.jpg" width="100" height="100" border="0" alt="img" usemap="#img">
<map name="img">
<?php while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($db_erg, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>      
    <area shape="rect" coords="10,10,30,30" href="" alt="#" title="" onmouseover="show('<?php echo $data['id'];?>');" onmouseout="hide('<?php echo $data['id'];?>');" />
    <div class="show" id="<?php echo $data['id'];?>">
        <?php echo $data['text'];?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</map>
```

Function: A div with the corresponding content and at the mouse coordinates should be open when the mouse is on an area.

Comment: jsfiddle pls? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The problem was outside of the scope stated in the question and is not likely to be reproduced in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tX25a/2/

```
div=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
btShow=document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
btHide=document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1];
btShow.onclick=function(){
    document.body.onmousemove=function(event){
        var e=event||window.event;
        div.style.left=e.clientX+"px";
        div.style.top=e.clientY+"px";
    }
    div.style.display="block";
}
btHide.onclick=function(){
    document.body.onmousemove=function(){};
    div.style.display="none";
}
```

Works for me on FF17ESR, OS/2, should work on IE and WebKit as well.
If you want the block to disappear onmouseout and appear onmouseover, rather than on buttons' clicks, then just define the proper event handlers.

Comment: ok thx on firefox it works, but ie will not work

Comment: @user2961059 why? have you tested? `e=event||window.event` is a recommended way to get the event object on IE. What fails? May I have the console log?

Comment: your script works fine, i think their is a problem with the read id

Comment: @user2961059 who are them, and what exactly their problem is?

Comment: i read the id of a database, so that i can assign each div the correct area...the problem is the div will not displayed, therefore i think there is a problem with the id or something else